# Triangle.gs server not starting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

When I got on this morning, it was having problems. Many. All of our achievements restarted and none of the nether portals were working. I've been looking at it all day to try and fix it. I went in to "start" my server but it always says offline after that. I looked in the Console thing and this is what it says * Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile server.jar
Command running:
Starting server process ...
/start: line 155: echo: write error: No space left on device
/start: line 154: echo: write error: No space left on device

I looked on how much megabytes its taking but it still says 0. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Reason for voting as "unclear": No idea what "triangle.gs" is or if it is even related to Minecraft.

Comment: It was a server provider, but seems to have stopped (their website is 'for sale'). Problems are likely due to their policy, or versions, or plugins, so finding a solution seems unlikely and irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking at the log, it explicitly states "No space left on device". I recommend contacting your hosting provider (triangle.gs in your case) and asking them to fix it.